# Flutter Firebase Crashlytics app rejected by Apple for missing Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

My flutter app is using **firebase crashlytics** ONLY, there are **NO** push notification implemented in my flutter app. However Apple rejected my app for missing Missing Push Notification Entitlement. I tried to manually turn to false

```
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
```

in `GoogleService-Info.plist`

but issue is persist. anything I can do without adding push notification entitlement?